# Pivoting data in SQL - TERADATA

Tags: sql, pivot

Trying to pivot a table data to get the output shown in the image below. Current table ---> Expected table. Can someone please guide me on this? 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHpAY.jpg)

Comment: Can you share what you've tried so far? Resources on that is readily available https://www.revisitclass.com/teradata/pivot-function-in-teradata-with-examples/

Answer (score 0):

Pivot converts the rows of a column to seperate columns and unpivot does the opposite. Here, in your case you want the value column to have its data as columns likewise below takes value in pivot and considers each value from `IN` clause.

```
 Select * from table
  Pivot (value for value in
   ('1,234','5,678',...)
```

Its similar to `case when` if you want different names to your row data made columns then use `case when` with group by

```
  Select value, max(case when 
   value='1234' then value end) as
   Value1, max(case when... End) 
   As value2.. From table group by id;
```